# Rails loop with number_field params?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I use two number_field to get numbers, and `if minor_sum > minor`, I will create `minor_sum - minor +1` objects.

```
<%= f.number_field :minor, :class => "form-control" ,placeholder: "(1~9999)" %>
<%= number_field :minor_sum, nil, :class => "form-control" , placeholder: "(1~9999)" %>
```

But when I enter two number **111,112** and create, It's shows

> comparison of String with Array failed

and mark this line:

> if minor.present? && minor_sum.present? && minor < minor_sum

the following is my controller:

```
def create
    minor = params[:beacon][:minor] if params[:beacon][:minor].present?
    minor_sum = params[:minor_sum] if params[:minor_sum].present?

    if minor.present? && minor_sum.present? && minor < minor_sum.to_i

        while minor < minor_sum
          @beacon = Beacon.new(beacon_params)

          ...

          minor += 1
        end 
    else
       ...
    end
end
```

Does it means that I got params from number_field is not number? How yo solve it?

I tried **.to_i**, shows:

> undefined method `to_i' for ["112"]:Array

mark this line:

> if minor.present? && minor_sum.present? && minor.to_i < minor_sum.to_i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`minor` is a `String` and `minor_sum` is an `Array` of `String`s (it's not clear why it's an `Array`, you may check the name of the input generated as HTML). You were on the right track, to compare them with the current code, you'd need to cast them to `Integer`s:

```
minor = params[:beacon][:minor].to_i if params[:beacon][:minor].present?
minor_sum = params[:minor_sum][0].to_i if params[:minor_sum].present?

if minor.present? && minor_sum.present? && minor < minor_sum.to_i
  ...
```

I'd recommend that you debug and find why you're getting the `params[:minor_sum]` value as an `Array`, though.